# MySQL Workbench : Automatic events

Tags: mysql-workbench

i'm trying to get sql queries to automatically run every few seconds/minutes/days on 3 databases created in sql workbench. I've looked everywhere for a tutorial or information on how to do so with no luck. I can create events through sql query e.g. CREATE EVENT, and they get stored but never seem to execute on the timestamp. What am i missing, or is there another program i should use?

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

First enable the global event scheduler:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

You can check if it is running by doing:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Your created events should now execute.